# How do I uninstall bundler on AWS (& difference btw local and system wide gems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems

When I run `bundle install` on my AWS instance, I get this syntax error on my gemfile:

```
Gemfile syntax error:
/var/www/mheesen.cc/releases/20131206072125/Gemfile:18: syntax error, 
unexpected ':', expecting kEND
...tter-bootstrap-rails', github: 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-r...
                              ^
```

This is an error typically associated with me having Ruby 1.8 installed, but by typing `ruby -v` I get `ruby 1.9.3`.

Digging a little further, I read "[error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10574436/766570)", and figured that it could be because my bundler is using a system Ruby rather than a local one. (I'm not exactly sure how that works, but oh well.)

I thought the best remedy was to uninstall the `bundler` gem and reinstall it and hopefully it will pick up the right bundler with the right Ruby version but trying to uninstall on my project directory gives me this error:

```
path/to/my/project$ gem uninstall bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    bundler is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global bundler
```

This confirms my suspicion that it's using a system-wide bundler, but then trying to uninstall that system-wide bundler gives me a permission error:

```
gem uninstall -i /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global bundler
Remove executables:
    bundle

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  Y
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the 
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin directory.
```

I tried changing the permissions on the said folder.. didn't have the permissions to do that either.

Trying to update bundler on my project also tells me that everything is up to date.

What do I do now? What are my options? I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix:

```
$ cd /var/www/mheesen.cc/releases/20131206072125
$ sudo gem install bundler # Since "bundler is not installed in GEM_HOME"
$ sudo bundle install
```

Long fix:

It seems you have RVM installed as a system package, probably through `sudo apt-get install rvm`. If possible uninstall that and install it using [RVM install guide](https://rvm.io/rvm/install). Do not install using `sudo`.

Steps:

```
# Uninstall system package RVM (in flavor of RVM user install method)
$ sudo apt-get remove rvm

# Don't edit your bashrc. RVM alone will attempt to setup your shell (2013)
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

$ rvm requirements  #=> will install gawk, g++, libreadline6-dev, etc...
$ rvm install 1.9.3
$ rvm use --default 2.0.0
```

You should enforce the ruby version to use within a `.ruby-version` file within your project's directory (commit this changes and deploy again) with this content:

```
$ vim .ruby-version
1.9.3
```

As a bonus you can completely replace old system ruby 1.8.7 with latest and greatest:

```
# Use this to replace old 1.8.7 on your system
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git
$ cd ruby-build
$ ./install.sh

$ ruby-build 2.0.0-p353 /usr/local
```

Notes on GEM_HOME and related:

> GEM_PATH provides the locations (there may be several) where gems can be found
>
> GEM_HOME is where gems will be installed (by default)
>
> Therefore GEM_PATH should include GEM_HOME

Comment: thanks man.. i got a question: so what is `GEM_HOME`? and for every gem.. is there like a global gem and a local gem?

Comment: also I was reading on RVM's [docs](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics) and it mentioned the following: `RVM also lets you use different rubies in a manner that wont mess with your existing ruby install`. I thought RVM was the only way to install ruby.. is there a way to install ruby other than via RVM?

Comment: unfortunately the short answer didn't work.. I got this error: gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.5.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/cache/bundler-1.3.5.gem

Comment: and with the long answer.. i don't have permissions to set the default ruby version with rvm! i'm getting:  `rvm --default use 1.9.3
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484': Permission denied`.. why would aws deny me access to such a thing?

Comment: Add sudo to those commands when you get permission denied `sudo gem install bundler` and `sudo rvm --default use 1.9.3` i didn't realize you have rvm installed system-wide (probably installed through sudo apt-get install rvm)

Comment: I updated the long answer and added GEM_HOME notes. Hope it helps

Comment: hey thanks @elgalu.. i'll definitely give your answer another good look + some research since it's obvious there is a lot I gotta learn (i'm a rails noob who just got thrust into a big project).. and i'll definitely give you the award as soon as i solve the problem based on your instructions

Comment: hey @elgalu I just wrote [my own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20630677/766570) answer.. it's more of trying to make sense of what's going on.. lemme know if its sound.. nothing worse than a half truth lol.. I also awarded you correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

although the answer got correctly [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20454495/766570).. I'll put down some notes just for my own reference (and hopefully it can be useful for others).. I'll explain with an example:

suppose we would like to kill the `thin` server running on our AWS.. to do that we:

- run `ps aux | grep thin`
- find the pid and then run `sudo kill -9 pid`
- **here is the important part:** to restart the server, we run `rvmsudo thin start -p 80 -d`

  - `-p` is to chose port number, `-d` is to run as a daemon

notice how we are using `rvmsudo` rather than just `rvm` (note, this is specific to rvm.. don't go around thinking you can just stick sudo to any random command) and that's because as mentioned above there are two kinds of gems:

1. System wide
2. Local

when you type sudo install gem or sudo gem do something, `sudo` puts you in the system environment, thus you are using system wide gems.

likewise.. if you just install a gem without sudo then u're just installing a local gem. That being said.. you may still want **local gems to perform actions that require root permission..** that's when rvmsudo comes into play and you do something like `rvmsudo thin start ..`.. you are using a local gem but while having root permissions.

Comment: Thanks for writing this clarification! i also found another and will put here as an extra reference: 

`sudo` starts a new subshell that do not contain environment variables.   
`rvmsudo` passes on any env var that RVM setup to get you to the correct Ruby. This includes the `$PATH` as well has `$GEM_HOME`, `$GEM_PATH` and `$BUNDLE_PATH` variables.

Comment: mmm.. so @elgalu you mean to say that RVM has it's *own* env variables other than the shell? what's the point of that?

Comment: The point is to notice that $GEM_HOME, $GEM_PATH will be passed by rvmsudo to the sudo subshell which otherwise wouldn't be passed.

Comment: hey @elgalu.. sometimes when i run an rvmsudo command i get this: `$ rvmsudo thin start -p 80 -d 
Warning: can not check `/etc/sudoers` for `secure_path`, falling back to call via `/usr/bin/env`, this breaks rules from `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=1

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.

In case there is no `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`. Run:

    export rvmsudo_secure_path=0

to avoid the warning, put it in shell initialization file to make it persistent.`

Comment: what does that message mean? could it mean that i'm not using rvmsudo as i should?

Comment: I was never faced to that warning @abbood, I would do what it says, enter `export rvmsudo_secure_path=1` in your `$HOME/.bashrc` or whatever you are using