# Phusion Passenger: There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, passenger

Passenger is amazing when it "just works" (as advertized), but when it doesn't, it's so hard to figure out what is actually going on.

```
There was an error in your Gemfile, and Bundler cannot continue. 
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:12:in `rescue in evaluate'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:6:in `evaluate'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:135:in `definition'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:123:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:219:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:333:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:217:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Tinkering with `bundler` source revealed the actual exception message:

```
cannot load such file -- rubygems/format (LoadError) (Bundler::GemfileError)
```

which is not terribly informative either, but at least it looks like `bundler` is run in a wrong environment. Executing `bundle` under the user the app runs at yields:

```
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
It was installed into /home/appname/www/shared/bundle
```

Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you use rvmsudo when you ran bundle install

Comment: no, just `bundle install`. the gems are really there where bundler says they are. I'm not sure why /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler is invoked...

Comment: Check out the comments on the accepted answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574405/error-in-your-gemfile-and-bundler-cannot-continue even though your using ruby 2.0 bundler might be using 1.8  If those comments don't help you, post your gemfile

Comment: Well, Passenger just loads your application, catches any exceptions that your app throws during startup, and presents it to you. There's nothing it can do about the actual cause of the problem because that's outside Passenger's control.

As for not being able to load rubygems/format: maybe it's a permission problem. Check the UID and environment variable dump in the error page. Are they correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up reinstalling `rvm` and `passenger` from scratch, and it worked...